Making a nested structure from interfaces type-safe
I want to make a developer-defined object type-safe with generics to avoid typos in properties. The interfaces can cross-reference each other with properties, sometimes as a one-dimensional array of a specific type. null marks the last element of the nesting but this was chosen arbitrarily by me.
The structure can be nested as deep as the developer wants and should only allow properties of the type of the higher level property's type - but not all properties do, some are number, string, etc.
This is the basic interface structure with an example (expander):
interface Base {
    id: string;
}

interface Foo extends Base {
    name: string;
    subFoo: Foo;
    bars: Bar[];
}

interface Bar extends Base {
    description: string;
    foo: Foo;
}

const expander: Expander<Bar> = {
    foo: null, // correct
    foo: { bars: { foo: null } }, // correct
    foo: { baz: null }, // should error b/c baz is not a property of Foo
    baz: null, // should error b/c baz is not a property of Bar
};

What I have tried so far:
type BaseOrArray = Base | Base[];
type Expander<B extends BaseOrArray> = {
    [P in keyof B]: B[P] extends BaseOrArray ? Expander<B[P]> | null : never;
}[keyof B];

But this is giving me an error:

Type of property 'bars' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ [P in keyof Foo]: Foo[P] extends BaseOrArray ? Expander<Foo[P]> | null : never; }'.


"I want to make a developer-defined object type-safe" please note if you are writing a code for other developers to consume then that's on them, not you. Certainly you can and should make it easy as possible for them, but you ultimately only have fairly limited control over how someone else uses your thing. If you are making a utility type for other devs as you seem to be, remember that it has to be both easier and shorter than just typing the relevant definitions out by hand, and significantly so to make it worth adopting. Are you sure even if you get this working it will clear that bar?

@JaredSmith This is true for any type system and since Typescript gives me the ability to be more expressive, I want to leverage that to avoid nasty bugs that can easily make their way through code reviews. Typos are quite common in large repos. Yes, it will help tremendously because today was the third time this month where I had to point this out a typo in a code review and I want to get rid of this.

I think you may have missed my point. That's all well and good for the technical problem, but you have/will have a people problem: those individual developers have to, when writing code, remember to/be willing to use your thing...

I don't get what you mean. I have a technical problem because people type names wrong, a lot, quite a lot which is costing us time and thus resources. I want the structure type-checked with the type system Typescript is giving me. Type systems were invented because people type stuff wrong, all the time. If this solely was a people problem, we'd still be using assembly everywhere. But we don't, we have things like Typescript. So I'm using types in Typescript.

Maybe this approach is what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz This is working perfectly, thank you so much! If you could briefly explain it, I'd be very thankful but if you don't have time, I will mark your answer as accepted regardless.

Here's one possible approach:
type Expander<T extends BaseOrArray> =
  T extends readonly Base[] ? Expander<T[number]> : {
    [K in keyof T]?: null | (T[K] extends BaseOrArray ? Expander<T[K]> : never)
  };

This is a recursive conditional type. First, it seems that you want Expander<X[]> to be equivalent to Expander<X>. So the initial conditional type just checks to see if T is an array, and if so, return Expander<T[number]> for the array element type (we index into T with number to get the array element type).  If it's not an array then it's a Base-compatible object. Here we produce a mapped type so that each property at key K of T becomes an optional property (using the ? mapping modifier) whose type is essentially Expander<T[K]> | null. There's a wrinkle in that T[K] might not be a BaseOrArray, so we check it. If it is one, then we get Expander<T[K]> | null. Otherwise we just get null.
That produces the following type for Bar:
let expander: Expander<Bar>;
/* let expander: {
    description?: null | undefined;
    foo?: {
        name?: null | undefined;
        subFoo?: Expander<Foo> | null | undefined;
        bars?: Expander<Bar[]> | null | undefined;
        id?: null | undefined;
    } | null | undefined;
    id?: null | undefined;
} */

And you get the behavior you're looking for:
expander = { foo: null }; // okay
expander = { foo: { bars: { foo: null } } }; // okay
expander = { foo: { baz: null } }; // error
expander = { baz: null } // error

Looks good.

Note that I'd say the primary reason the version of Expander in the question cannot work is that you are making it an indexed access type {⋯}[keyof B] which possibly you pattern-matched from somewhere? That format looks like a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. But you really don't want to do that, since it produces a union of all the properties, not an object type. And when you apply it to a recursive type like Foo or Bar, you'll end up with a circularity error as it needs to fully descend into the type to produce a result. Evaluation of object types can be deferred (since once the property keys are known it can wait), but indexed access types are eagerly evaluated.
Playground link to code
